# How to get rid of exponential value in python matplotlib bar graph? Instead of exponential values I want 0.1, 1, 10,100 and 1000

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting bar graph using python matplotlib as shown in figure below. I am trying to get rid of exponential values on y axis but couldn't get rid of it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

# set width of bar
barWidth = 0.25
fig = plt.subplots(figsize =(12, 8))
params = {'legend.fontsize': 20,
          'legend.handlelength': 2}
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=20)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
plt.rc('axes.formatter',useoffset=False)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
# set height of bar
dpkt_val = [0.06, 0.33,0.58,3.02, 7.01]
scapy_val = [0.59, 2.41,5.85,24,56.15]
pyshark_val = [26.26,152.94, 261.14,1456.02,0] #

# Set position of bar on X axis
br1 = np.arange(len(dpkt_val))
br2 = [x + barWidth for x in br1]
br3 = [x + barWidth for x in br2]
plt.rcParams.update(params)
# Make the plot
plt.bar(br1, dpkt_val, color ='r', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='dpkt',hatch='*')
plt.bar(br2, scapy_val, color ='g', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='Scapy',hatch='//')
plt.bar(br3, pyshark_val, color ='b', width = barWidth,
        edgecolor ='grey', label ='pyshark',hatch='-')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')

# Adding Xticks
plt.xlabel('Filesize', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Time(sec)', fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 20)
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(dpkt_val))],
        ['100MB', '500MB', '1GB', '5GB', '10GB'],fontsize = 20)

plt.yticks(style='normal',fontsize=20)
plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Instead of exponential values, I want 0.1, 1, 10,100, and 1000.
Any help is appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wweIB.png

Comment: As BigBen mentioned in the answer's comments you can slightly change to `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(12, 8))` and then add `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set log scale, that is, in your code, just before the last line, `show`

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
# (...)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```

(`gca` get the default axes your are plotting ont. And the next line choose a scalar formatter for labels of y axis)

Comment: Indeed. Corrected for log. And corrected for the 0 (using strformatter, with '%g', instead of the ScalarFormatter of my initial answer). And I saw (just after replying) that OP indeed had already imported scalar formatter. Which make me think they had already tried that.

Comment: ``` 
ax=plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
```
It solved the issue.